# PROGRESS ODBC SQL Covert string into time

Tags: sql, odbc, progress

i need to convert string into time. I have 2 columns, one of them have date in good format but time looks like this:

```
Time
_____
061923
060239
134803
135011
```

first 2 characters are hours, second 2 are minutes and last 2 are seconds. How to convert it into format like "HH:MM:SS" ? Im using progress odbc.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert `':'` into the string and convert to a time:

```
select cast( (left(col, 2) + ':' + substring(col, 3, 2) + ':' + right(col, 2)) as time)
```